# no getting user control property from webpart

Tags: 2007, development, web-part

I am using this MSDN tutorial but it is not working,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649867.aspx

When I try to get a usercontrol value, nothing comes up

```
try
{
    // Loads a user control
    MyUserControl myUserControl = (MyUserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/_controltemplates/MyWebPart/MyUserControl.ascx");
    myUserControl.Web = SPContext.Current.Web;
    myUserControl.TextColor = this.TextColor;
```

The Usercontrol intellisense is not coming up with textcolor.

Answer (score 1):

i solve the mistake i was using

```
UserControl myUserControl = (UserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/_controltemplates/MyWebPart/MyUserControl.ascx");
```

whenever i was needing to use,

```
MyUserControl myUserControl = (MyUserControl)Page.LoadControl("~/_controltemplates/MyWebPart/MyUserControl.ascx");
```